# Remove a specific reaction emote on any message (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to make a "banned reaction". I got the following code working, but it only removes reactions for messages the bot sends.

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
  console.log(reaction);

  if(reaction.emoji.name === 'pinkphallicobject')
    reaction.remove();
});
```

How can I get it to remove a specific reaction for all messages from anyone?

Answer (score 1):

For the `messageReactionAdd`event to fire on old messages you will need to cache the old messages in the server when the `ready` event is fired you can do it like this:

```js
client.once('ready', () => {
    var guild = client.guilds.cache.first();// you can find the server you want it to work on in a different way or do this for all servers
    guild.channels.cache.forEach(channel => { 
        if(channel.type == 'text'){//do this for text channels only
                channel.messages.fetch({limit: 100}).then(() => {
                console.log('cached 100 or less messages from the: ' + channel.name + 'text channel.');
            });
        }
    });
}
```